# PHP division adds a comma

Tags: php, floating-point

I'm trying to convert cents to dollars (I don't need dollar sign, just value) but when I divide a number smaller than 100 by 100 I get a strange result.

Eg.: 1/100 give me 0,01.0

I don't need that comma, I need 0.01 as it should be.

I also tried number_format but it returns a string and when I cast the result to float I get the same strange value.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help

This is the function I'm using:

```
public static function convertFromCents($value) {
    if(is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = $value/100;
    } else {
        $value = 0;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

This are the proof of what I'm saying:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code?

Comment: @El_Vanja I just did it, thanks

Comment: This code won't produce the output you have stated (`0,01.0`). Can you also show how you use this function?

Comment: @El_Vanja please take a look at the screenshots I just added

Comment: It seems like something your IDE is reporting, not an actual value. Have you run the code? Have you tried to dump the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you see are messages of your IDE, not the real value of your variable.

In order to achieve what you want, you can simply use [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.
The second parameter is precision, which determines how many digits will appear after the point:

```
// return 0.33333333333333
echo 1/3;

// return 0.33
echo round(1/3, 2);
```

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot I added

Comment: It looks like the value you see is what your php editor calculates, not what the php engine does.